# Applying scikitlearn preprocessing to pandas without causing warnings

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use scikitlearn's preprocessing to min-max scale a row on pandas. My solution works but gives me 2 warnings and I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Here is my function which does the minmaxscaling given a dataframe and columns

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
def minMaxScale(df, cols):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    return scaler.fit_transform(df[cols])
```

This is where I use it

```
df.loc[:,'pct_mm'] = minMaxScale(df,['pct'])
```

Where the column 'pct' exists and 'pct_mm' does not exist.
I get the following warning 2 times:

**A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead**

How should I do this the way pandas wants me to?

Comment: i cannot reproduce your error... are you on a older version of pandas / python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the warnings:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

def minMaxScale(df, cols):
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    return scaler.fit_transform(df[cols])

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df.loc[:, 'newcolumn'] = minMaxScale(df, ['sepal_length'])
```

However, if I do this:

```py
df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df2 = df[:]
df2.loc[:, 'newcolumn'] = minMaxScale(df, ['sepal_length'])
```

then I get two warnings as well.

Probably you derived `df` from another dataframe somewhere in your code. I recommend you to find the lines where you used `df`, and make sure to make a copy, like: `df = old_df.copy()`.

Comment: I definitely did so you must be right. I rename my dataframes a lot when I make changes so I can access past changes, is that not good practice? Or should I always copy() when I rename it?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Maybe yeah, it's a good practice, but I usually make a copy when I see such warnings as well haha. Logically, it would be good to make a copy for every new dataframe derived from another one if there's no memory issues, since your ideally you're storing a distinct set of information... that's a good question =)